# How to resolve Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, mocha.js, aws-iot, pem

I have a Typescript project where I read in `AmazonRootCA1.pem` for fully functioning `AwsIotRestApi`. That is, when I run the API it seems to be working just fine. I want to test the API with mocha. When I attempt to do so I get the following error:

```
Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
```

`AmazonRootCA1.pem`, the file which is being read is correctly formatted, so I'm not entirely sure how to go about solving this. Would anyone know how to resolve this error?

Comment: Care to share your test code and the code you are trying to test?

Comment: *"the file which is being read is correctly formatted"*  How did you confirm this?

Comment: Dit you fix this and how?